# Estimate the wavelength of an oscillatory signal

Tags: python, power-spectral-density

I need to estimate the dominant wavelength of a signal that is looking like this:[image]
My first attempt was using `scipy.signal.argrelmin` in Python in order to detect the minima of the signal, but it detects also very small local minima. Is there any useful method for this that I should look into? (The wavelength that I would like to measure is the one between the pronounced minima in the above figure)
The data for this solution can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/Omer80/wavelength).

Comment: have you checked if `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt` works (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html)?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use it, but I still don't make a lot of sense to it...I will keep on reading in this direction, so thanks

Comment: can you provide the data somewhere on the internet?

Comment: Shouldn't a (log) spectral analysis work? The reciprocal value of the dominant frequency should give you the dominant wavelength no? What am I missing?

Comment: @ruohoruotsi: Maybe with only 3 of these peaks a spectral analysis would not show a strong peak at the correct frequency.

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé the data for this signal are here - https://github.com/Omer80/wavelength

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the code snippet below to find the three peaks in the graph. Note, that peak search usually only searches for positive peaks. Hence, I negated the signal to search for the down-peaks. Also, I adapt the SNR threshold in the code to detect only the very strong peaks.

```
import urllib2
import scipy.signal as signal

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Omer80/wavelength/master/oscillations.dat'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = np.loadtxt(response)
X = cr[0,:]
Y = cr[1,:]

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(Y)

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(X, Y)

peakind = signal.find_peaks_cwt(-Y, np.array([100]), min_snr=5)
peakind = np.array(peakind)
print peakind


plt.stem(X[peakind], 1+0*peakind);

period = int(np.mean(np.diff(peakind)))
print "Period between peaks:", X[period]-X[0]
```

Output:

```
[1919 2500 3080]
Period between peaks: 0.145036259065
```

[image]

Comment: Is the any difference in calculating the period with `period = int(np.mean(np.diff(peakind)))
print "Period between peaks:", X[period]-X[0]` instead of `np.mean(np.diff(X[peakind]))` ?

Comment: This wont make a difference, it's also possible.